# Fibonacci terms with primal distances

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Given any prime $p$, are there fibonacci numbers $F_k $ and $F_n$ such that $|F_n - F_k|=p^i , i \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: The edit - to include prime powers, rather than just primes - makes it very unlikely that there is an easy answer. What motivates this question, and do you have any reason to think the answer might be "yes"?

Comment: Every Fibonacci number bigger than 1 [except F(6)=8 and F(12)=144] has at least one prime factor that is not a factor of any earlier Fibonacci number. Working on this

Comment: You will find that every integer is a factor of infinitely many Fibonacci numbers, in particular $p^i$ will be  factor of infinitely many - so you will find that there are pairs of Fibonacci numbers both divisible by $p^i$ whose difference is divisible by $p^i$. What I don't see is how you hope to get anywhere close to equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $p=17$ is not a difference of any pair of Fibonacci numbers up to 34 (by inspection). If either $F_k$ or $F_n$ is $>34$, then their difference is either zero or $\ge 55-34=21$. Therefore $17$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Got it. Erasing comment...

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried? $17$?

The terms of the Fibonacci sequence show exponential growth, and the gaps grow faster than the primes.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of instances where $F_m - F_n$ give rise to primes, but there are many more primes than there are $F_n$ or differences of thus.

All the same, if $m-n$ is a multiple of $3$ or $4$, then the outcome is a multiple of $2$ or $3$.